Is it shirk to have the username 'The Egglord'?
I have a discord account and the display name is called The Egglord. Now, many people are attacking me on it as being shirk. Is this true?
I do not intend to be a god or whatnot. I just named it because i loved eggs and i just had a lot of them in my pantry. So, I named myself that name. Now, many people are bullying me that it is pure shirk as calling yourself the lord of something is haram and implies you are a god, which is not true. I intended the name to be a joke way, as in king, like a royal member that owns an army of eggs, a commander you could say. Please help me on this!
